# Django Rest Auth using google authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth, django-rest-auth

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('', GoogleLogin.as_view()),
    path('auth/google/callback/', google_callback, name='google_callback'),
    path('auth/google/url/', google_views.oauth2_login)
]
```

views.py

```
import urllib.parse
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google import views as google_views
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import include, path, reverse
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView


class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = google_views.GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    client_class = OAuth2Client

    @property
    def callback_url(self):
        return self.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('google_callback'))


def google_callback(request):
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode(request.GET)
    return redirect(f' http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/google/callback/')
```

Client ID for Web application

URIs :http://127.0.0.1:8000
Authorised redirect URIs : http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/google/callback/

error:
Authorization Error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Learn more
The content in this section has been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed or verified by Google.
If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.

```
redirect_uri: http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback/
```

**Pl help me. Thank you in advance.
django-rest-auth using google authentication any reference documentation pl share me.**

Comment: Seems like you are re-directing to 'localhost:8000', but at the Google end you've registered '127.0.0.0:8000', as the redirect URI. Can you register both and see if this makes a difference?

Comment: I have trying but giving me same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have problem `User` model with UUID primary key and after restore default `id` field it start work

https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/551#issuecomment-1858911936

My example of using django-allauth and dj-rest-auth

users/views.py

```py
class GoogleLoginRedirect(RedirectView):
    url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URL(WITH OUT SLASH IN THE END)>&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&scope=openid%20email%20profile&access_type=offline"
    permanent = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.url


import requests
class GoogleCallback(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        code = request.GET["code"]
        response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/dj-rest-auth/google/", json={
            "code": code
        })

        django_response = HttpResponse(
            content=response.content,
            status=response.status_code,
        )
        for k, v in response.headers.items():
            django_response[k] = v

        return django_response
```

urls.py

```py
    path('dj-rest-auth/google/', GoogleLogin.as_view(), name='google_login'),
    path("dj-rest-auth/google/login/", view=GoogleLoginRedirect.as_view(), name="google_redirect"),
    path("dj-rest-auth/google/callback/", view=GoogleCallback.as_view(), name="google_callback"),
```

UUID primary key not work for
django-allauth = "~0.56.1"
dj-rest-auth = "~5.0.2"